# What happens if I don't handle audio interruptions?

Tags: iphone, audio, openal

Is it possible to still play sound / music even if audio has been interrupted, or more precisely: even if MyInterruptionListener got called from the OS with the interruption state kAudioSessionBeginInterruption ?

Yeah I know that's not good idea to do. But want to know anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time you get an interrupt message, the audio resources you've been using have been shut down.

For AVAudioPlayer, playback will be stopped until you start it again.

For OpenAL, your context will be invalid. All OpenAL commands will fail with an error until you clear the current context and set it to current again.

For Audio Units, your graph will be in an invalid state. No sound will be played until you set the graph inactive and then active.

I don't know what would happen if you tried to start your audio resources again upon getting an interrupt start message, but at the very least you'd get rejected in the app store if the reviewers ever discovered this behavior.